# How to create a list of tuples in python?

Tags: python, list

I have a function which accepts a list of tuples. I only have an array of integers and want to convert it into list.

I have this:

```
[1,2,3]
```

What I want:

```
[(1),(2),(3),(4)]
```

Comment: What you actually want, I believe, is `[(1, ), (2, ), (3, ), (4)]` because `(1)` is simply a parenthesised expression.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a list of tuples using a list comprehension:

```
>>> tuples = [(x,) for x in [1, 2, 3]]
>>> print(tuples)
[(1,), (2,), (3,)]
```

The comma in `(x,)` is the tuple operator which makes the comprehension create tuples rather than just ints.